# Unit testing void public methods

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class that I am trying to write a few unit tests for, specifically, a void method within the class. Im not entirely sure whether or not the fact that the method is void is of any consequence here, but this is the basic structure of the class.

```
public class MyClass {
   private Map<String,Object> myMap;

   public void process(Bucket bucket){
      //parses bucket, updates myMap
   }

   public int getAnswer(String input){
      //searches map data
   }


}
```

The basic usage of the class is that the process method is called for each bucket to ingest it’s data, and the getAnswer method returns a summation of sorts about the data that has been processed from the buckets.

I’ve written a few unit tests for the getAnswer method, but since the process method doesn’t return anything, but rather just updates the internal state of my object, is there a way to properly unit test it? Since it’s a public method, I figured that it needed to be unit tested, but haven’t figured out how to do so, independent of the getAnswer method.

Comment: I would consider a unit test sufficient if it calls `process` with proper input and then calls `getAnswer` corresponding to the input and asserts that the output of the second methods matches what you expect. At that point you have tested both methods since `getAnswer` cannot return valid output unless `process` also works properly. The only alternative I see would be to make *something* accessible for testing purposes, e.g. the `myMap` or a getter for it.

Comment: You can make the method return a boolean response instead of it being void, and then do an assertion.

Comment: I made an initial answer, but if you share more code I can dive in more details

Comment: @SatyamRaj Unit tests are not a good reason for changing production APIs. And a simple boolean as a return value is almost completely useless regarding unit tests. It would make much more sense to just keep it void and throw an exception on errors. But even then you can only meaningfully tests failures. Positive tests still need a different way to verify the results.

Answer (score 3):

We would need more code to answer you in details, but in short the answer is yes, you can and should definitely test it.

`process` is going to make some side-effects somewhere, right? Either you inject Mockito mocks of the classes/interfaces these side-effects are effected upon, or if you have an in-memory version of them you inject that instead.

In the case of mocks, you'll want to carefully assert that the side-effect methods were called exactly with the right parameters. If you're using an in-memory simulation, you check the state of your in-memory object and check it conforms to what you expected.

Comment: In a code review spirit, the correct approach is to separate the processing of the data and the storage of the data into separate components (single responsibility principle) and unit test the components separately.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have fixed ideas on things like that, it depends on the logic and its complexity. I answered in general how one can and should test void methods. If we get more details I'll update as needed ;)

Comment: A perfect solution for perfect world... Sometimes it exists, I swear. Anyhow, difficulties in unit testing are so often caused by the code not following single responsibility and dependency inversion principles that it is warranted to be spelled out. What you suggested was just that, I just added the technical terms that can be thrown in a search engine. :)

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing of `process` method, I think you can do following:

1. Verify input `bucket` can be able to parse based on your method comments.
2. Exception handling -- if applicable --  if `bucket` is unable to parse.
3. For map update / add, you can always check if initial size is changed & valid bucket made successful attempt to add to map. If bucket key already present, you can also verify if size of map remains same.

All above points are based on information provided in original question & it is independent of `getAnswer` method.